# Why do I receive a Failure when attempting to uninstall Facebook via ADB?

Tags: android, adb, samsung-galaxy

Good evening everyone,
I'll cut right to the chase, and forgive me if this has already been answered elsewhere and I just didn't find it:

I'm attempting to uninstall some of the bloatware that shipped with my S22 Ultra 512 GB phone. I never use apps like Facebook, nor do I use Google's search engine. Similarly, I will be phasing out Gmail in the coming years. Suffice to say that between Meta, Inc and Alphabet Inc, there are about 50 gigs worth of data that are being used up on my phone. I want that back. So, I installed adb tools, updated my drivers, and attempted to uninstall Facebook first. I used the following command:

```
`pm uninstall -k -user 0 com.facebook.katana`
```

I receive the following failure:

```
'Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Missing existing base package]'
```

It seems like it's saying that Facebook isn't installed on my device, but it definitely is.
I have also confirmed that it's not a system "bloatware" issue by attempting to uninstall one of the apps that I am "allowed" to uninstall using the same command. I receive the same failure.

I want it off. Please help.
Thank you for your time.
~Tom

I tried to use the commands to remove Facebook and Google. I expected them to be removed.

Comment: Note that Android Enthusiasts may be more appropriate: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=uninstall+system+app

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry; I didn't know that was a thing. Next time I have a question about this subject, I'll be sure to post it there instead.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add `-k` and `-user` not valid flag `--user` is.
Try something like `pm uninstall --user 0 package_name`

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it for me. I didn't see that there were two hyphens and that was the problem.  Much appreciated. I don't have the necessary reputation to publicly upvote your answer, but I tried to! I appreciate it. <3